# Does the Van der Pol equation with negative parameter explode outside a circle?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider the [Van der Pol system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator)
$$
\mathrm{\frac d {dt}}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}y\\\mu(1-x^2)y-x\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\mu < 0$. It attains an asymptotically stable equilibrium at the origin. Is there a circle centered at the origin such that for every trajectory that starts outside the circle, $\|x\| \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$? It definitely looks like it, but I don't know how I'd prove it.

Comment: Yes, it has an unstable limit cycle and no other equilibria. So every trajectory that starts outside of the limit cycle has nowhere else to go other than to infinity. This can be proved by the same phase plane methods that prove the limit cycle stable for $\mu>0$, but global analysis is tricky.

Comment: Yep, "global analysis is tricky". A rough outline of a possible proof would be enough; I can fill in the details.

Comment: If you change $t$ to $-t$ in the second order van der Pol equation you get equation where the sign of $\mu$ is reversed. In other words, the trajectories of your equation are the trajectories of the van der Pol oscillator traveled in reverse. The stable limit cycle becomes unstable and the trajectories that approached it from outside now unwind from it and go to infinity.

Comment: Maybe you can prove it using the Poincare-Bendixson theorem, or try to pose it as a Liénard system..?